# Is there a way to exclude an apostrophe “s” from entities in spaCy’s NER component?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am performing named entity recognition (NER) in the context of a custom entity linking component using spaCy 3.2 (I am running into the same issue with the latest 3.3 version as well).

When performing named entity recognition on texts that contain an apostrophe “s” (e.g. `Apple's`), I would like to exclude the apostrophe “s” from the named entity the component returns.

In instances where the named entity includes a single token in addition to the apostrophe “s”, the NER component correctly returns only the named entity token (e.g. `Apple` instead of `Apple's`):

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

s = u"Apple's looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion"
doc = nlp(s)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(f"{ent.text} (lemma={ent.lemma_}): {ent.label_}\n")

Apple (lemma=Apple): ORG
U.K. (lemma=U.K.): GPE
$1 billion (lemma=$1 billion): MONEY
```

```py
for token in doc:
    print(f"{token.text} (IOB={token.ent_iob_}): {token.ent_type_}")

Apple (IOB=B): ORG
's (IOB=O): 
...
```

However, when I perform named entity recognition on texts where the named entity spans multiple tokens (e.g. `Apple Inc.` instead of `Apple`), the apostrophe “s” is included as a part of the returned named entity:

```py
s = u"Apple Inc.'s looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion"
doc = nlp(s)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(f"{ent.text} (lemma={ent.lemma_}): {ent.label_}\n")

Apple Inc.'s (lemma=Apple Inc.'s): ORG
U.K. (lemma=U.K.): GPE
$1 billion (lemma=$1 billion): MONEY
```

```py
for token in doc:
    print(f"{token.text} (IOB={token.ent_iob_}): {token.ent_type_}")

Apple (IOB=B): ORG
Inc. (IOB=I): ORG
's (IOB=I): ORG
...
```

There is no difference in tokenization between these texts (i.e. the `'s` portion is split out as its own token in both cases). I do not want the apostrophe “s” to be included in the named entity for entities like `Apple Inc.'s` and would like the NER component to return only the `Apple Inc.` portion of this named entity.

Is there a way to configure the NER component to prevent this behavior with multi-token named entities and exclude the apostrophe “s”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to simply configure the component not to do this. What you can do is use a small custom component to remove `'s` from any entities.

```
def my_component(doc):
    out = []
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent[-1].text == "'s":
            out.append(ent[0:-1])
        else:
            out.append(ent)
    doc.ents = out
    return doc
```

See [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components) for info on how to use it.